# How to mark check box as a checked in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I am very new in angular 2. i need to mark check box on a button click.
i have some checkbox in a loop like

```
 <tr *ngFor="let roleObj of roleNameList">
      <td>
         <input type="checkbox"   id ={{roleObj.roleID}} />
     </td>
     <td>{{roleObj.roleName}}</td>
  </tr>
```

i have one array of selected role, only i need to mark those check boxes on a edit button click . so what i did like same in javascript

```
 document.getElementById("role").checked
```

but in angular 4 there is no property like that.

i searched and found there is one property binding for

> [checked] ="somevariable"

but the problem is same property [checked] ="somevariable" will add on all checkboxes. the result is when i assigned the somevariable as true. it will mark all the checkboxes.

other solution I have in jquery like

```
$(document.getElementById(role)).prop('checked', true);
```

but might be it can create problem, i am not sure please correct me.

please help me. any clue or logic will same my days.

Comment: Make `sameVariable` a property of `roleObj`, and only update the relevant ones

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can modify your object to also include a boolean `checked` property (i.e. `roleObj.checked = false`) and dynamically update the relevant ones when you need to.

Then you markup simply becomes

`<input type="checkbox" [checked]="roleObj.checked"  id ={{roleObj.roleID}} />`

Comment: thanks for your reply. i got you logic but could you please correct me why we should not use jquery logic

Comment: Well, given that you are building an Angular application, I would try to keep it as clean and angular-y as possible. Everything you can do with jQuery, you can do with standard Angular logic (pretty much) so I would try not to mix the two. The Angular version is also usually much cleaner, readable and reusable than a jQuery alternative

Answer (score 3):

You can follow this simple implementation

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <input type="checkbox" 
    [checked]="selected === item.id " 
    [value]="item.id" 
    (change)="selected = item.id"
    [attr.id]="item.id"
    /> 
   <label [attr.for]="item.id"> {{ item.label }}</label>
  </ng-container>

  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  items = [
    { id: 1, label: 'one' },
    { id: 2, label: 'two' },
    { id: 3, label: 'three' }
  ];

  selected = 1;
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f3gmdk)

Answer (score 2):

You should use variable. In your .ts:

```
public checkboxValue: boolean;
constructor() {
  this.checkboxValue = false;
}
```

And in your .html:

```
 <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checkboxValue"/>
```

You should remember to add FormModule in your @NgModule:

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
         FormsModule      
    ]
```