# How to replace "TRUE" with a checked checkbox and "FALSE" with a nonchecked checkbox in an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a table that is formatted as

**Code:**

```css
  #daily {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #3C4AB8;
    color: white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 80vh;
    width: 90vw;
    border: 10px solid #222A68;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    }


    #table thead th {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
    }
    
    td,
    th {
        border: solid #E3DAFF 2px;
        padding: 0.5rem;
    }
    
    th {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        border-top: none;
        background: #222A68;
        top: 0;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 8px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    td {
        border-bottom: none;
        white-space: wrap;
    }
```

```html
   <table id="daily">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="year">year</th>
                    <th class="cutoff">cut off date</th>
                    <th class="name">Stefan</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th class="name">Johnny</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th class="name">Effie</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th class="name">Karol</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th class="name">Vardan</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th class="name">Aman</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th class="name">Jaspal</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th class="name">Laurent</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-sheetdb-url="https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/xxxxxxxxx?sheet=Dashboard" data-sheetdb-sort-by="age"
                data-sheetdb-sort-order="desc">
                <tr>
                    <td id="date">{{year}}</td>
                    <td class="cutoff"><i>{{cut off date}}</i></td>
                    <td id="hours">{{Stefan}}</td>
                    <td class="checkbox">{{c1}}</td>
                    <td id="total">{{Johnny}}</td>
                    <td class="checkbox">{{c2}}</td>
                    <td id="total">{{Effie}}</td>
                    <td class="checkbox">{{c3}}</td>
                    <td id="total">{{Karol}}</td>
                    <td class="checkbox">{{c4}}</td>
                    <td id="total">{{Vardan}}</td>
                    <td class="checkbox">{{c5}}</td>
                    <td id="total">{{Aman}}</td>
                    <td class="checkbox">{{c6}}</td>
                    <td id="total">{{Jaspal}}</td>
                    <td class="checkbox">{{c7}}</td>
                    <td id="total">{{Laurent}}</td>
                    <td class="checkbox">{{c8}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

This table fetches some data from a Google Sheet using https://sheetdb.io/ as a backend. There are values in some cells that are checkboxes returning as either "TRUE" or "FALSE".

How can I replace these values with checkboxes that are checked when the value is "TRUE" and unchecked when the value is "FALSE"?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use the `checked` attribute to make an input appear as checked. I'm not super familiar with Angular, however something like this should get you moving in the right direction: [Another resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49904531/how-to-mark-check-box-as-a-checked-in-angular-4)

<input ... [attr.checked]="value ? 'checked' : null"/>

Comment: Where are the checkboxes? Tried anything yet?

Comment: @wazz `$('.checkbox').html('<input type="checkbox">');` does work for replacing all `.checkbox` classes with a checkbox input. However, that does not solve my problem. I need "FALSE" to be an unchecked checkbox and "TRUE" to be a checked one.

Comment: Problem 1) You have multiple duplicate IDs. Ids **MUST** be unique.

Comment: Solved with

`window.addEventListener("sheetdb-downloaded", function() {

    $('.checkbox').each(function(index, el){
        if (el.innerHTML.trim().toLowerCase() == 'true') {
            el.innerHTML = '<input class="checkbox_r" type="checkbox" checked="checked">';
        } else {
            el.innerHTML = '<input class="checkbox_r" type="checkbox">';
        }
    });

});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen for the sheet loaded event

```
//Event listener for sheet loaded
window.addEventListener("sheetdb-downloaded", function () {
  //Iterate the checkbox items
  $(".checkbox").each(function () {
    //debug logging
    console.log($(this).text() == "TRUE")
    //UPdate the html based on loaded content
    $(this).html(
      `<input type="checkbox"${
        $(this).text().toUpperCase().trim() == "TRUE" ? " CHECKED" : ""
      }>`
    );
  });
});
```

[Pen](https://codepen.io/nobloss/pen/rNGGwBY)

Comment: Solved it with

`window.addEventListener("sheetdb-downloaded", function() {

    $('.checkbox').each(function(index, el){
        if (el.innerHTML.trim().toLowerCase() == 'true') {
            el.innerHTML = '<input class="checkbox_r" type="checkbox" checked="checked">';
        } else {
            el.innerHTML = '<input class="checkbox_r" type="checkbox">';
        }
    });

});
`

but I think yours might work as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can user prop method of jquery

```
$("#yourCheckboxId").prop("checked", value)
```

if the value is true the checkbox will be checked and if the value will be false the checkbox will be unchecked

Answer (score -1):

this will enumerate all td with class checkbox and replace all TRUE/FALSE inside with checkboxes

```
$("table#daily tbody td.checkbox").each(function(){
    var td = $(this);
    var txt = td.text().toUpperCase().trim();
    if (txt == "TRUE") {
        td.html('<input type="checkbox" checked>');
    }
    if (txt == "FALSE") {
        td.html('<input type="checkbox">');
    }
})
```

Comment: This looked very promising, but sadly has not produced any result. I'm not sure why - the logic does seem to make sense :/

Comment: then show what you have before and what you need to have after in html

Comment: have a look at the [codepen here](https://codepen.io/stefanyas/full/MWEEgzm). Essentially, I have succeeded at replacing all the `.checkbox` classes with a checkbox, but that does not really tell me if it's a `TRUE` or `FALSE` value. I'd want for a value of `TRUE` to have a checked checkbox, while for the value of `FALSE`, I'd like to have an unchecked box. Is this possible?

Comment: if you need to convert checked state into string with value TRUE/FALSE  use this construction: `val = $("#checkboxId").is(":checked") ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";`